# Laravel 5.7: pdf file gets stored in folder

Tags: php, laravel, file, pdf, storage

I'm trying to store a pdf file within a folder, but there are strange things happening whether I use a Laravel-Helper to get the file or if I get it through it's validation(Form Request).

Assuming I get the pdf file and store it like this:

```
$file = $request->validated();  <-

$uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
$id =  $uuid->toString();

if ($order == 'cat1') {
  $path = '/orders/cat1/' . $id;
  Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
  Storage::put($path.'/cat1.xml', $xml);
  Storage::put($path.'/cat1.pdf', $file);
}
elseif (empty($order) || $order == 'cat2') {
   $path = '/orders/cat2/' . $id;
   Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
   Storage::put($path.'/cat2.xml', $xml);
   Storage::put($path.'/cat2.pdf', $file);
}
```

assuming `$order` is  `cat1` the files will be stored like this:

*> : folder | - : file*

```
>orders
  >cat1
    >1234567890($id)
      -cat1.pdf
      -cat1.xml
```

This is exactly how it should turn out, but the `cat1.pdf` hasn't been uploaded successfully, if I try to open it I get an error.

But when I get the file with a Laravel functions to check if it was uploaded successfully (found it in the docs) like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {    
   $file = $request->file('file');  <-
   if ($file->isValid()) {          
      $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
      $id =  $uuid->toString();
      if ($order == 'cat1') {
         $path = '/orders/cat1/' . $id;
         Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
         Storage::put($path.'/cat1.xml', $xml);
         Storage::put($path.'/cat2.pdf', $file);
       }
       elseif (empty($order) || $order == 'cat2') {
         $path = '/orders/cat2/' . $id;
         Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
         Storage::put($path.'/cat2.xml', $xml);
         Storage::put($path.'/cat2.pdf', $file);
       }
```

Then the file will be stored like this:

```
>orders
  >cat1
    >1234567890($id)
      >cat1.pdf
        > nVeY7HjwLLy[...].pdf (random id by Laravel)
      -cat1.xml
```

And like this the pdf file is successfully uploaded, I can open it.
But for a reason I don't know the pdf file is stored in another folder even though I use the exact same way to store it.

**What's the difference between the two ways to get the pdf file and how does it affect the file storage?**

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: @Sohel0415 I'm using 5.7

Comment: then use `putFileAs()`, follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: @Sohel0415 could you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: I think its not necessary, you find the solution and make it worked that's the most important matter

Answer (score 0):

For the uploaded files, you should use the `store` / `storeAs` (laravel) OR  `move` (UploadedFile(symphony)  methods to store the file.

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {    
    $file = $request->file('file');  <-
    if ($file->isValid()) {          
        $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
        $id =  $uuid->toString();
        if ($order == 'cat1') {
            $path = '/orders/cat1/' . $id;
            Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
            Storage::put($path.'/cat1.xml', $xml);
            $file->storeAs($path, 'cat1.pdf');
        }
        elseif (empty($order) || $order == 'cat2') {
            $path = '/orders/cat2/' . $id;
            Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
            Storage::put($path.'/cat2.xml', $xml);
            $file->storeAs($path, 'cat2.pdf');
        }
    }
}
```

with the `storeAs` / `store` method you can also specify the disk you want it to go to.
more info [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#storing-uploaded-files)